# What "-X" stands for in SSH

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, remote

I want to connect to the user interface of remote machine from my own laptop.
I used `ssh -X user_name@machine_ip` to connect the remote user interface.

However it just logged-in the command line shell.

Hi can I connect to the user interface of remote machine?

Comment: You can use `VNC` for connect to UI. this instruction may help you : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: -X' Enables X11 forwarding with ssh.

Answer (score 3):

[ssh man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)

> -X' Enables X11 forwarding. This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.

Running `ssh -X user_name@machine_ip` will log you into the remote machine, with X11 forwarding.

The meaning of X11 forwarding means that you'll be able to execute GUI commands on the remote machine, and the GUI will be shown on your local screen.

e.g. you will be able to run on the remote machine:

**Ubuntu System Monitor** using:

```
gnome-system-monitor
```

**Firefox** using:

```
firefox
```

You can try to  start the GNOME desktop environmen using:

```
gnome-session
```